# Unable to get VFS File object for filename issue

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, pentaho

I am new to hadoop ,i am using apache `hadoop 1.0.3` and using `redhat linux 6.0 vm` ,while i am trying to load a sample file from local windows 7 to Hadoop 'HDFS' file system, ,i used the sample guidelines from the url:http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Loading+Data+into+HDFS ,but while running the job i am getting the following error ,**`

> Unable to get VFS  File object for filename
>   hdfs://192.168.10.130:54310/home/hduser

Please help me to resolve this,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

PDI doesn't support Hadoop 1.0.3 out-of the-box, I wrote a blog post that describes how to build a hadoop configuration for PDI:

http://funpdi.blogspot.com/2013/03/pentaho-data-integration-44-and-hadoop.html

Once you create a hadoop config, you need to set it as the active one according to the instructions here:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Configuring+Pentaho+for+your+Hadoop+Distro+and+Version

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply i have little bit confusion in the given instructions, under the pentaho-bigdata folder i was unable to find the any plugin.properties file,and my jar files like 
commons-codec-<version>.jar
hadoop-core-<version>.jar are under libext folder,and its matches with the hadoop lib folder configuration files ,still i am not able to rectify the issue,please help me on this.

Comment: Your hadoop-*.jar files should not be in libext. What version of PDI are you using?